# Nonlinear model fit with Numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting, nonlinear

I'm having trouble writing a Nonlinear Model fit where the model is a numerical integral evaluated with NIntegrate. I have read other questions and answers about more or less the same problem, but for some reason I cannot make sense of this. Here goes:

I define a function containing the integral:

```
    LumDist[zmax_?NumericQ, Om_?NumericQ, Ol_?NumericQ, Ot_?NumericQ, 
  n_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/\[Sqrt](Om*(1 + x)^3 + Ol + Ot*(1 + x)^n), {x, 0, zmax}]
```

and from there define the model:

```
DistMod[zmax_?NumericQ, Om_?NumericQ, Ol_?NumericQ, Ot_?NumericQ, 
  n_?NumericQ, mu0_?NumericQ] := 
 5*Log10[LumDist[zmax, Om, Ol, Ot, n]] + mu0
```

From here I write a NonlinearModelFit for this model (data) is an (x,y) List:

```
lmvar = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, {DistMod[z, 0.28, 0.71, Ot, 10^(-3), mu0], 
   1 < Ot >= 0}, {{Ot, 0.08}, {mu0, 23.89}}, x, Weights -> 1/errors^2,
   VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &), Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

But this does not work, and I get lots of errors such as:

```
NIntegrate::nlim: x = z is not a valid limit of integration. >>
```

and

```
NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0.01012` cannot be used as an iterator. >>
```

Here is a sample of the data and errors:

```
data = {{0.015, 34.1114},{0.0277, 35.705},{0.048948, 36.7316},{0.0651, 37.3067},{0.100915, 38.4567},{0.159, 39.4164},{0.248508, 40.2722},{0.455, 42.3239},{0.655, 42.3151},{0.75, 43.243},{0.84, 43.5143},{0.961, 44.2642},{1.188, 44.6076},{1.34, 45.0675},{1.414, 44.8038}}

errors={0.215239,0.118114,0.175773,0.242628,0.121087,0.21481,0.152213,0.306006,0.188809,0.198402,0.471047,0.1534, 0.421,0.213,0.1345}
```

**Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?**

Moreover, I can even write another simpler model (it's completely wrong, but I want to try to isolate the problem):

```
testfunc[a_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a*t, {t, 1, x}];
```

Which I can try to fit using:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, {testfunc[b], b > 0.}, b, x, 
 Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

but this also throws lots of errors, such as:

```
NonlinearModelFit::nrnum: The function value 1/2 ((-26.877+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-26.2011+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-26.1609+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-26.0592+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-26.0071+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-25.9072+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-25.7394+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-25.6034+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+<<35>>+(-24.5574+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-24.548+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-24.5443+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-24.5128+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-24.4717+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-24.4442+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+(-24.4217+testfunc[0.0914636])^2+<<996>>) is not a real number at {b} = {0.0914636}. >>
```

Comment: In the first case, don't you need to give `z` a numeric value?

Comment: Since we do not have data, we can not help anything. Or do we have to come up with data?

Comment: I provided a data set with errors in my post.

Comment: There are 15 data points and 11 errors.  Adding in the additional errors is necessary as we can't know which data points have missing errors.

Comment: That's my mistake, I added some errors. It doesn't really matter what they are.

Comment: Should the `x` in `NonlinearModelFit` be `z`?  Also you have the restriction `1 < Ot >= 0`. Should that be `0 <= Ot < 1` ?  And why would you set the known variance to 1 (with `VarianceEstimationFunction -> (1&)` ?  Fixing the typos and removing `VarianceEstimationFunction` gets everything to work - although the fit is poor suggesting a different model is necessary.

Comment: I was under the impression (from other posts) that VarianceEstimationFunction -> (1&) tells the fitting algorithm that my weights are actually measurement errors. See this link: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/FitModelsWithMeasurementErrors.html

Comment: I might very well have gone overboard with my `VarianceEstimationFunction` complaint (and I'll respond about that later today - either justifying or retracting that comment) but the main issue is the typo that `x` should be `z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your simplified example is that you don't explicitly incorporate `x` in `NonlinearModelFit`. A solution, albeit a completely incorrect one, can be found with a slight modification to `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
testfunc[a_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a*t, {t, 1, x}];
NonlinearModelFit[data, {testfunc[b,x], b > 0.}, b, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

To really test what is going on here, a slightly more flexible model could be introduced. Changing `testfunc` just a bit:

```
testfunc[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a*t^b, {t, 0, x}];
```

Now, `NonlinearModelFit` can be used to find a reasonable fit:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {testfunc[a, b, x], a > 0, b < 0}, {a, b}, x]
(*FittedModel[testfunc[2.65151,-0.939799,x]]*)

nlm["ParameterTable"]
(*  
Estimate    Standard Error  t-Statistic P-Value
a   2.65151 0.0537729   49.3094 3.59017*10^-16
b   -0.939799   0.00114251  -822.574    4.78556*10^-32
*)
```

Showing the solution:

[image]

There is a similar error in the definition of the actual function of interest. You should be able to find a fit with:

```
LumDist[zmax_?NumericQ,Om_?NumericQ,Ol_?NumericQ,Ot_?NumericQ,n_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[1/\[Sqrt](Om*(1+x)^3+Ol+Ot*(1+x)^n),{x,0,zmax}]
DistMod[zmax_?NumericQ,Om_?NumericQ,Ol_?NumericQ,Ot_?NumericQ,n_?NumericQ,mu0_?NumericQ]:=5*Log10[LumDist[zmax,Om,Ol,Ot,n]]+mu0

lmvar=NonlinearModelFit[data,{DistMod[z,0.28,0.71,Ot,10^(-3),mu0],0<= Ot<1},{{Ot,0.08},{mu0,23.89}},z,Weights->1/errors^2,VarianceEstimatorFunction->(1&)]

(*FittedModel[DistMod[z,0.28,0.71,0.999999,1/1000,44.5454]]*)

lmvar["ParameterTable"]
(*
    Estimate    Standard Error  t-Statistic P-Value
Ot  0.999999    0.727728    1.37414 0.192627
mu0 44.5454 0.3562  125.057 2.05428*10^-21
*)

Show[Plot[lmvar[x], {x, 0, 2}], ListPlot[data]]
```

[image]

Note, the problem with the original call to `NonlinearModelFit` did not include the dependent variable (in this case `z`). You might be able to find a better fit playing around with the options of `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: `testfunc` will no longer need `NIntegrate` as `Integrate` can be used.  Further a reasonable fit would be with taking logs of both the the response and predictor variable and fitting a straight line.  The `errors` vector might not even be needed or appropriate:  looking at the residuals would help with that decision.

Comment: How long did that take you to run? My real dataset has just over 1000 points and it is taking a long time to run.

Comment: Using the 15 points from the original `data`, `RepeatedTiming` is showing somewhere in the neighborhood of 12 seconds on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

One of the problems is that the model is over-parameterized by 2 or more parameters.  Below are some algebraic steps that shows at least two of the parameters can be replaced by a single parameter.  (That at least two additional parameters can be replaced by a single parameter is not shown but the evidence is in examining the parameter `CorrelationMatrix` from `NonlinearModelFit`.)  This suggests that either just taking the logs of the response and predictor variable and fitting a straight line is what should be done or rethinking of the original model is necessary.

Here is the definition of `LumDist` where we extract `Om`:

[image: Extracting Om]

The final model (`DistMod`) can therefore be written as follows:

[image: Description of DistMod]

We see that we can only at best estimate $-10 \log_{10} O_m+\mu_0$ and not $O_m$ and $\mu_0$ separately.

**End of update**

There are (still) a few typos in the original question.  If `x` is changed to `z` in the `NonlinearModelFit` statement, the restriction `1 < Ot >= 0` is changed to `0 <= Ot < 1` (or as written it might even be equivalent to `Ot > 1` - can't really tell), and `VarianceFunctionEstimation` is removed, the model converges:

```
lmvar = NonlinearModelFit[data, {DistMod[z, 0.28, 0.71, Ot, 10^(-3), mu0], 0 <= Ot < 1},
   {{Ot, 0.08}, {mu0, 23.89}}, z, Weights -> 1/errors^2];
lmvar["ParameterTable"]
```

$$\begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 \text{Ot} & 0.999999 & 2.42865 & 0.411751 & 0.68723 \\
 \text{mu0} & 44.5454 & 1.18875 & 37.4725 & \text{1.2436775876447106$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-14} \\
\end{array}$$

It appears that the use of the parameter `Ot` is not very useful as the fit is poor and the estimate is at the boundary.

A much better fit can be found by noting that a log-log plot appears to be a simple straight line

```
ListLogLogPlot[data]
```

[image: Log log plot of data]

Fitting such a model we have

```
lmvar2 = NonlinearModelFit[Log[data], a + b logx, {a, b}, logx];
lmvar2["ParameterTable"]
```

$$\begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 a & 3.7851 & 0.00207508 & 1824.07 & \text{1.526517371336953$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-36} \\
 b & 0.0601371 & 0.00104813 & 57.3755 & \text{5.051558118117479$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-17} \\
\end{array}$$

```
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[{lmvar[z], Exp[lmvar2[Log[z]]]}, {z, Min[data[[All, 1]]], 
   Max[data[[All, 1]]]},
  PlotLegends -> {"Original fit", "Better fit"}]]
```

[image: Comparison of fits]

Assuming that the full dataset has a similar look and feel, this new approach not only provides a better fit but is much faster.

(I note that despite Wolfram producing [an example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/FitModelsWithMeasurementErrors.html) as to how to fit curves when there is measurement error, that example assumes (generally inappropriately) that there is only measurement error and assumes the more typical lack-of-fit error is zero.  So given that the measurement errors in this example (which I assume are standard deviations) are pretty similar among themselves, I'd even drop the use of `Weights`.)

Comment: This is indeed a much better fit, and I have thought about this, but then I need a way to translate this fit to parameter constraints on my original model, and I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: I think the problem is that the model is overparameterized by at least 2  parameters.  (Very loosely the data only supports the estimation of 2 parameters.)  One can definitely see that at least one of the parameters needs to be removed.  Consider factoring out `Om` from `LumDist` so that the integral is `f[Om]*integral`.  Taking the logs as `DistMod` does means that the model has the form `5*Log10[f(Om)] + 5*Log10[integral] + mu0`.  This means that you can only estimate `5*Log10[f(Om)]+mu0` but not `mu0` and `Om` separately.  That an additional parameter needs to be removed is more subtle.